# How to remove the uiview I created from navigationController when I move forward or back to next page?

Tags: swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I created a view programmatically and added to the navigationController as subview. The problem that I am facing now is that the view is not removed when i move forward to next page or the previous page. What can be done to remove the view or include the view in a particular view controller of the navigation controller only?

```
  self.footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 40, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
        self.footerView.tag == 1
        footerView.backgroundColor = themeColor
        let totalLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(16, 8, footerView.frame.width/2, 30))
        totalLabel.text = "Rs. 200"
        totalLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let button = UIButton(type:UIButtonType.Custom)

        button.frame =  CGRectMake(footerView.frame.width/2 - 16, 8, footerView.frame.width/2, 30)
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
        button.setTitle("Save and Continue", forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "saveButonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 2
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        footerView.addSubview(totalLabel)
        footerView.addSubview(button)
        self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(footerView)
```

Comment: Can you paste the code of view creation and add, with file name ?

Comment: 'self.footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 40, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
        self.footerView.tag == 1
         let button = UIButton(type:UIButtonType.Custom)
        button.frame =  CGRectMake(footerView.frame.width/2 - 16, 8, footerView.frame.width/2, 30)
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
        button.setTitle("Save and Continue", forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        footerView.addSubview(button)
        self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(footerView)'

Comment: edit your question and paste the code, so it is readable. thanks

Comment: where you have added this code ? please add file name

Comment: add full code of your viewcontroller class

Answer (score 0):

Create the same View in ViewController.

```
let customView = //your view creation code.
self.view.addSubview(customView);
//this will add view to your viewcontroller's view, not in navigationContoller.
```

You can remove the view,

```
customView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: I am addig the view in navigationcontroller and the view controller that I am using is UITableviewcontroller